# Use native reduce instead prototype 1.6.0.3 reduce

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm developing a third-party widget and my js uses native reduce function.

But, when I put in the customer page, it has prototype 1.6.0.3 library and it overrides the reduce function doing some thing completely unexpected.

How can I do for my JS to use native reduce instead?

Thanks

Comment: Store `Array.prototype.reduce` in a variable before Prototype gets loaded then reset `reduce`.

Comment: The problem is that as a third-party JS, i can't control where the client will put my script, above or below prototype.js

Comment: can you request that PrototypeJS be updated to 1.7.1? That version checks if native reduce exists before overwriting it and fixes many other bugs.

Comment: No, because this can affect other parts from customer website and he doesnt want to take that risk

Comment: Yes, and the most strange thing about Prototype.js own implementation is that it does an absolutely stupid thing: reduce: function() { return this.length > 1 ? this : this[0]; } WTF?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Florent's comment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Array.prototype.nativeReduce = Array.prototype.reduce;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/prototype.js"></script>
```

Now you can call the native reduce method like this:

```
var x = [];

x.nativeReduce(...);
```

If you cannot control the order in which scripts are imported, then an `iframe` might do the trick to at least gain access to the native `reduce` function again.

```
(function (document) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

    iframe.src = "about:blank";
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);

    var reduce = iframe.contentWindow.Array.prototype.reduce;

    // Rest of your script goes here

    var arr = [1, 2, 3];
    reduce.call(arr, function() { ... });
})(this.document);
```

Comment: The problem is that as a third-party JS, i can't control where the client will put my script, above or below prototype.js

Comment: @Cleyton: I'm only 5 years late replying to your comment, but I did find a workaround and updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found was to use .reduce function implemented in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

and rename it to reduceExt to not mess up with existing libs in the owners page.